# Python Programming with Class Definition

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

This is my code so far, the error I'm having so far is (name 'person' is not defined) on line `person.name = name`, I'm literally stuck & trying to figure out what is the issue/error since my code has to be based on the question I wrote below.I'm not sure if the remaining of my code has any errors since it is detecting that error first.

```
from datetime import date

class person:
    pass

def create_person(name, height, birthdate):
    person.name = name
    person.height = height
    get_age = birthdate
    return person

def get_age(person):
    birthdate = person.birth
    today = date.today()
    subyear = 0
    if today.month < birthdate.month or (today.month == birthdate.day and today.day <= birthdate.day):
        subyear = 1
    person.age = (today.year - (birthdate.year + subyear))
    return person.age

def get_description(person):
    return person.name + ' is ' + str(person.height) + ' cm high and is ' + str(get_age(person)) + ' years old'

def main():
    birthdate = date(1976, 8, 14)
    person = create_person('Michael', 190, birthdate)
    print(get_description(person))
```

This is the question:

> Write a class definition for the Person class and write user-defined
> functions with these function headers:
>
> ```
> def create_person(name, height, birthdate):
>   # Return a a new person object with the given name, height and birthdate.
>   # - name is a str
>   # - height is an int object in centimetres
>   # - birthdate is a date object from the
>   # module datetime
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ```
> def get_age(person):
>   # Return the age of the person in years.
> ```
>
> For example, assume today's date is June 12, 2018. if Mary was born on
> June 4, 2017, then Mary's age is 1. However, if Bob was born on June
> 14, 2018, then Bob would not have had a first birthday yet so the age
> is 0.
>
> ```
> def get_description(person):
> # Return a string object of the form: Name is
> # N cm high and is M years old, where N and M
> # are integers
> ```
>
> For example, Michael is 190 cm high and is 43 years old or Samantha is
> 95 cm high and is 4 years old.
>
> ```
> def main():
> # Create a person named 'Michael', with height
> # 190 cm, who was born on August 14, 1976 and
> # output a description of this individual.
> ```
>
> If you use a function from an imported module when writing your
> function, you usually declare the import statement at the top of your
> code.
>
> Here is a sample run of a main program that just calls the main
> function.
>
> ```
> Michael is 190 cm high and is 43 years old.
> ```

This is a hint I currently received:

> Use the date class from the datetime module to represent a date. An
> object whose type is date, has attributes: year, month and day that
> you can use to compute the age of a Person.
>
> To compute the current age of a person, you will need to first compute
> today's date. There is a method in the date class of the datetime
> module that creates a new date object that represents the current
> date. The name of this method is today. However, the special argument
> of this method must be the date class itself, instead of a particular
> object whose type is date. A method that is applied to a class object
> instead of to an instance of that class is called a class method.
>
> Therefore, to create the current date you can use the expression:
>
> ```
> date.today()
> ```
>
> since after importing the date class from the datetime module, the
> identifier date is bound to the date class object.
>
> To compute the age you can just subtract the year attribute of the
> birthdate from the year attribute of the current date. However, you
> will also need to check whether the person has already had their
> birthday yet this year and if not, subtract one year

Comment: You should indent the methods, and include self as parameter to the method. person.name =name should be self.name=name

Comment: This is really too much to read. You should try to create a [mcve], with some emphasis on _minimal_.

Comment: `person` indeed *isn't* defined on that line. Why did you think it would be? I don't think the exercise is very good, it's a bit weird to write a function that instantiates a class rather than just using `__init__` directly, but you should read https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html.

Comment: @stefan - that makes a lot of sense,  but the question demands otherwise. This must be a course on how to write really bad python.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I myself think it's weird but the topic is introducing me to create a `class`. Under the definition for `def create_person(name, height, birthdate):`, it says `Return a a new person object with the given name, height and birthdate. name is a str, height is an int object in centimetres and birthdate is a date object from the module datetime` which I think would be whatever the system inputs so if it uses for example: "Name = John, Height = 200cm and brithdate = May 15th, 1976".

Comment: Yes, I can see that, which is why I don't think it's good.

Comment: @zvone my apologies, it's just a lot of  class definitions that are included and the description better explains everything.

Answer (score 0):

Have `Person` create its own attributes

```
class Person:

    def __init__(self, name, height, birthdate):
        self.name = name
        self.height = height
        self.birthdate = birthdate
        
# why someone would write such a function is beyond me, but...
def create_person(name, height, birthdate):
    return Person(name, height, birthdate)

# test
p = create_person('myname', 100, '23-23-23')
print(p.name)
```

This produces

```
myname
```

Now the other functions will have a class instance they can use.

If you have a problem with any one of the functions, that's best posted in another question that focuses just on that problem. (removing functions / methods not needed to demonstrate the problem).

Comment: I tried the code you mentioned & it didn't work. It say `name 'person' is not defined`

Comment: I updated with an example showing that the class instance is created properly. If you get `object` takes no parameters, then you're doing something else. To be honest, I don't know how to get that error message without doing `object('something')` so I can't offer a good guess as to why you got the message.